# php redirect before curl completes execution

Tags: php, jquery, html, curl, meta

So we have a system that can alter what you see on a display. This code is meant to send the command being "argument" to that JQuery page.

The curl is working beautifully, but when we comment out the if statement that handles the redirection to an XML document. The redirect occurs and the Curl request is not executed. We need to understand why this is happening, when we remove the Redirects it runs the curl request. When the Redirects are in place the curl request is not executed.

Please help in finding the cause of this issue and a way to rectify the problem, we have to keep the redirects but if there is a better way of running the curl request, ie not using curl but something that would be great, any suggestion will be tested.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
    ob_implicit_flush(false);
    $argument = $_GET["argument"];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/sub/page.html?api_key=**********&device_id=************&argument=".$argument."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

  if($argument == 1) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service1.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 2) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service2.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 3) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service3.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 4) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service4.xml">';
  }
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see the curl request probably hasn't finished doings it's thing before the page does the rediection. Why not get a return value from the curl request and use that as a prerequisite to the if statement that follows?

ie:

```
$status=curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

if( $status==200 ){
  if($argument == 1) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service1.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 2) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service2.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 3) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service3.xml">';
  } else if($argument == 4) {
       echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service4.xml">';
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I added your suggestion to the file. When running the edit it still does the same thing, gets into the Status if statement and runs the redirection without finishing the Curl execution

Comment: Are you expecting a result from the curl request? Does that curl request cause some actions that could be monitored and a return value send back?

Comment: There are no returns from the Curl Request. It is just pushing/posting information to a preset Jquery html file, that file works perfectly. But this file which is needed keeps redirecting before the Curl can do the post to the Jquery document.

Comment: I put a 3 second time on the META redirect and its giving enough time now for the posting, i am also using your Status check as well to help. Thank you for your post. @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

From your point I can derive the following points.

1. PHP programs run in sequential execution, so obviously curl execution will run in first step then redirection happens to the XML document.

this is because due to curl execution time will be long

2. Make sure you are redirecting the page after the curl success

   ```
   $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   if($status == 200){
       if($argument == 1) {
           echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service1.xml">';
       } else if($argument == 2) {
           echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service2.xml">';
       } else if($argument == 3) {
           echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service3.xml">';
       } else if($argument == 4) {
           echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://adloc8tor.com/ussd/service4.xml">';
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so yes i placed this in the code and it still skips over posting/executing to the Jquery page.